# Django ORM How to query and get values when multiple conditions are fulfilled

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have following model

```
class TimePeriod(BaseModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    min_travel_days = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    max_travel_days = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)

    insurance_period_min_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True, blank=True)
    insurance_period_max_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True, blank=True)
```

and Product model is as

```
  class Product(BaseModel):     
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have the following sheet to calculate the min_days and max_days and insurance min max days.

| Insurance_period | Travel days | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-92 days | 1-30 days | 30 |
| 1-183 days | 1-90 days | 45 |
| 1-365 days | 1-90 days | 50 |
| 1-365 days | 1-180 days | 60 |

My problem is suppose I have 29 days as travel days and 90 days as Insurance days How do I calculate the value by using django query? As  the actual value for 90 days of insurance days and 29 days travel time is `30`.

I tried doing this way

```
    TimePeriod.objects.filter(product__name='silver',insurance_period_min_days__lte=90,insurance_period_max_days__gte=90,
min_travel_days__lte=29,max_travel_days__gte=29).values('value').first()
```

I am getting 4 different result as my query satisfies all condition of above table any way I can do to satisfy above table conditon? to get 30 as value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer I was missing order by

```
TimePeriod.objects.filter(is_business=True,policy__slug='silver',insurance_period_min_days__lte=91,insurance_period_max_days__gte=91,min_days__lte=30,max_days__gte=30).values('value').order_by('value').first()
```